# How to find most common words in a MySQL database and average a second column

Tags: php, mysql

So I have two columns of text in a MySQL database, an example would be as follows:

```
Name             Score
Henry Hodgens    4
Mary Hodgens     8
Jim Servan       2
Jane Servan      4
Hank Servan      6
Sarah Smith      10
Mary Smith       12
Henry Dobbins    2
Henry Jenkins    4
```

I need to run a query with PHP that can show the average of "Score", based on the most common occurrences of a single word in "Name".  So, it would show that "Servan" averages 4, "Henry" averages 3.3, "Hodgens" averages 6, "Mary" averages 10, in the order of most occurrences of the word in "Name".

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
SELECT
    AVG(t.Score) AS ScorceAvg,
    t.name
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            SUBSTRING(Table1.Name,1,INSTR(Table1.Name, ' ')) AS name,
            Table1.Score
        FROM 
            Table1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            SUBSTRING(Table1.Name,INSTR(Table1.Name, ' ')) AS name,
            Score
        FROM 
            Table1
    ) AS t
GROUP BY
    t.name
```

Answer (score 3):

This is very difficult to do inside of MySQL. It's great at storing and retrieving relational values, not so great doing this sort of computation. If you don't mind doing this inside of PHP, you can use the code below to count the frequencies.

```
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    foreach (explode(" ", $row['Name']) as $token)
    {
        $total[$token] += (int)$row['Score']; 
        $occurances[$token]++;
    }
}

// compute average by taking ($total[$token])/($occurances[$token])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is th perfect thing

```
SELECT distinct
       SUBSTRING(NAME, LOCATE(' ',NAME)+1) as NameED,
      (select
       avg(score)
       from avgscore
       where NameED = SUBSTRING(NAME, LOCATE(' ',NAME)+1)) as Score
FROM avgscore
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT sum(Score)/count(Name) as average FROM tablename where Name regexp "Mary";
```