# How to find the most common phrases (not word) in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database

I have a table which contains articles on movies. Each article has a title and many of them have common phrases in them.

I would like to do some analysis on the data and extract these common phrases along with a count of their usage.

Here is a simple example:

```
Title
------------------------------------------------
John cannot connect to Asian number
The backup service cannot connect to the client
Mary cannot connect her laptop to the network
```

From this data I would like to be able to extract the following:

```
Phrase                                             Count
-------------------------------------------------- -------
cannot connect                                     3
cannot connect to                                  2
```

*Note: Additionally I would also like to remove stopwords from the results if possible.*

My database is in MySQL and I'm using php to code. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: This problem is not ideally suited to SQL.

Comment: It could be a heavy task for a DB. Assume, you have 1000 records in the DB and each record has 100 words. Imagine a number of possible combinations? You can probably start with an easier task, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310860/how-to-find-most-common-words-in-a-mysql-database-and-average-a-second-column